# Permutations of a set of data in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, permutation

I have 10,000 items in a set whereby each must be made into triads.
I need an algorithm to efficiently find each triad.

For example:

{A,B,C,D,...}

1.AAA
2.AAB
3.AAC
4.AAD
...

all the way to ZZY, ZZZ.

The method I'm using is very inefficient, I created a nested forloop of 3 which iterates through an array, which has a run-time of O(N^3) and terrible on performance obvious. Which kind of algo and data structure would be better for this? Thank you

Comment: Please show your code (even if it's inefficient).

Comment: How many triads are produced?

Comment: this is the most efficient way. The amount of possible permutations is `n^k` which is  10000^3 = 10^12 in your case and you need to do at least one insertion for each of them

Answer (score 0):

> Function to print all permutations of K length from a set of n characters with
>   repetition of characters:

```
static void printKLengthPerm(char[] set, String prefix, int n, int k) 
{ 
    if (k == 0) 
    { 
        System.out.println(prefix); 
        return; 
    } 

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    { 
        String newPrefix = prefix + set[i]; 
        printKLengthPerm(set, newPrefix, n, k - 1); 
    } 
}
```

> Calling the function to print all permutations of 3 length from a set all capital english alphabets:

```
char[] set = new char[26]; 
for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
  set[i] = (char)(i+65);
int n = set.length; 
printKLengthPerm(set, "", n, 3);
```

Comment: This has the same cubic time complexity as the one in the question, moreover this has O(k) space complexity due to recursion which means even worse overall performance since the OPs code has a constant space compl.